# Uncaught No element defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using [gmaps.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VNav.jpg). I'm getting the `Uncaught ReferenceError: gmaps.js:205 Uncaught No element defined.` The following screenshot shows how Chrome reports the error in the gmaps Javascripts:

But i have it true in  **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjgbchaa/5/)**, but same code on my localhost (XAMPP) problem.

[image]

```js
    var map = new GMaps({
    el: '#map',
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333,
    click: function(event) {
        map.removeMarkers();
        var lat = event.latLng.lat();
        var lng = event.latLng.lng();
        alert(lat + ', ' + lng);
        map.addMarker({
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng,
            draggable: true,
        });
    }
});
$('select,input').change(function() {
    var searchString = [$('select.Country').val(), $('select.Cities').val(), $('input#SearchDistrict').val()].join(', ');
    alert(searchString);
    GMaps.geocode({
        address: searchString.trim(),
        callback: function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
                map.addMarker({
                    lat: latlng.lat(),
                    lng: latlng.lng()
                });
            }
        }
    });

});
```

```css
#map {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
  <script src="https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js"></script>
<form>
    Country:
    <select class="Country">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
    </select>
    Cities:
    <select class="Cities">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="New York">New York</option>
    </select>
    District:
    <input type="text" id="SearchDistrict">
</form>
        <div class="popin">
          <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
```

I am not able to fix this, so I need your support.What do i do?

Comment: The code snippet doesn't exhibit the error.  Neither does the fiddle.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue or describe how to cause the error to occur with the examples you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the script and it works fine. The error you see happens only if `<div id="map"/>` does **not** exists in moment you create the map.

What you should do is to call the map creation script **after** you insert the map container into DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var element =  document.getElementById('map');
    if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
  {
    map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    zoom:,
    lat:,
    lng: ,
  });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also stuck in this problem and I notice that they are find node directly and call the function serially, the problem is ones above element didn't find it'll not further compile/run.

```
mapBasic();
mapMarker();
mapGeolocation();
mapGeocoding();
mapPolylines();
mapPolygone();
mapRoutes();
```

so in our case if `mapBasic` element is not find the further code is not execute.

Hope it may help you.